# Use of multicols in listing causes unexpected alignment

Tags: align, listings, multicolumn

The sole difference of the following two codes is the use of `multicols=2`. And this causes the alignment of `parbox` in `Code 1` wrong -- though alignment `t` is given, the typeset seems like alignment `b`.

How to correct it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,multicol}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Code 1:\par
  \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
    \begin{lstlisting}[multicols=2]
      ab
      cd
      ef
      gh
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
\vrule\ 
\fbox{\parbox[t]{1in}{ab}}

\bigskip
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Code 2:\par
  \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
    \begin{lstlisting}
      ab
      cd
      ef
      gh
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
\vrule\ 
\fbox{\parbox[t]{1in}{ab}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default multicol boxes have their baseline at the bottom. You can use a \vspace to topalign the minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

Code 1:\par

  \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
  \vspace{-\splittopskip}
    \begin{lstlisting}[multicols=2]
      ab
      cd
      ef
      gh
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
\vrule\
\fbox{\parbox[t]{1in}{ab\\blub}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the length `\splittopskip` rather than other lengh is used? Or how can I get the length value used in `\vspace` to topalign the minipage?

Comment: I used \showoutput to check which skips are used and then tried.

Comment: I copied `\showoutput` in my code and get nothing. Would you show me an example how to use it?

Comment: look in the log-file.

Answer (score 2):

I you want to have the first case vertically aligned as you second case, use `\null` just before `\begin{lstlisting}[multicols=2]`. It crates an empty line, your `\fbox` will be aligned by it.

Comment: Many thanks! As you say, `\null`  crates an empty line that makes the following `\fbox` aligned, but the extra empty line is not expected. How to eliminate this empty line?